# how can i specific data offset option in smbclient command?

Tags: linux, centos, cifs, smbclient

**How can i set data offset value in smbclient get command?**

I have a scenario where i need to download file from where it fails.
Here is the command i am using as of now:

`smbclient -U 'username' -c 'get filename.ext -' //ip/sharepoint 'password' -W domain --max-protocol SMB3 -p 445`

where should i do modification in order to achieve this functionality`enter code here

Comment: Can you mount the share? I believe mounting the share will turn your problem into "continue copying from one file to another". The new problem is general, not specific to SMB, Samba or `smbclient`. Standard tools can be used, they don't need to know anything about SMB. Have you tried this approach? Can you?

Comment: Okay thank you,can you please help me with command to mount cifs or nfs?